# Download all remote (xml)files under remote directory to local directory over sftp with node.js

Tags: node.js

I want to download number of xml files from remote server to local server via sftp node js

```
var client = require('scp2');
client.scp('admin:password@host:/home/project/Reports/ADC_GKJ_details.xml', '/data/apps/board/Reports/', function(err) {
    console.log('Completed');
})
```

Here we can able to download single file successfully but can't multiple files like /home/project/Reports/* OR /home/project/Reports/*.xml how to achieve this concept please help me anyone.

Comment: Have you tried to pass `admin:password@host:/home/project/Reports/` ?

Comment: I have  tried admin:password@host:/home/project/Reports/ this also but files not downloaded.